# WordPress not performing direct update

Tags: functions, updates, upgrade

I recently modified my server configuration and then I noticed Wordpress would no longer upgrade automatically and I was asking for FTP information to perform the upgrade.Irony is that I don't have standard FTP access, it's all SFTP.

I reverified the file/directory permissions and group.

I am really stuck, please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Add this option to your wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

I faced this problem way back long...this option helped me.